# My Menu Navigation on elementor is not showing the titles

Tags: wordpress, header, menuitem, elementor

I did some updates in my website but now i’m having problems with the menu on my mobile, i create a header for the mobile version of the website and the Titles of the menu are not showing, they look ok while I’m editing and they are also working normal on the desktop but when I published they look like this: #768 (NO TITLE)

Try to contact elementor but they didn't asnwer, try to change the page layout, create a new menu, create a new header, talk to my hosting suport but they couldn't help, nothing works, don't know what else to do because I don't know what is causing the problem.